# Configure Desktop + devices in Azure AD using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was not able to find the creation of (Desktop + devices) platform resource feature of terraform (**azuread_application**)  also attached screen shot for the azure portal.

**Mobile & desktop Platform screen shot **

[image]

Terraform code:

```
# AAD AKS kubectl app

resource "azuread_application" "aks-aad-client" {
 display_name               = local.app_name
 sign_in_audience           = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
 

 web {
    redirect_uris = ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"]
    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
    }
  }
  
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    resource_access {
      id   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User"]
    description          = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "user"
    enabled              = true
    value                = "Task"
  }
}
```

There are multiple options is available.But How can I configured the (Desktop + devices) platform?

[image]

If it's possible please provide az command for (desktop + devices) creation or terraform code.

Regards,
Nataraj.R

Comment: `redirect_uris` is different than what you want?

Comment: @marcin: I tried, it doesn't work also pasted the code in above.

Comment: Hello @Nataraj, can you please provide your full terraform code that you are using to create an application registration in Azure AD.

Comment: If you want to create the app using terraform as you have shown in second image , then you will have to use azurerm provider : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I have updated the terraform code in description. is it possible to provide any sample terraform script for mobile & desktop resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Web App using the below sample script from Github.

GitHub: https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-app-service

And in default App setting block you can add another setting as

```
MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION = "Latest"
```

As per the [Microsoft documentation for creating a mobile app](http://MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION).

**Update:**

I could add the platform using terraform by adding a `reply_uris` parameter in the `azuread_ application` resource block and it got added.

```
provider "azuread" {

}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
name     ="Your azuread app display name"
reply_urls = ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient","https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"]
}
```

after its added in portal its showing as web but it has the same configuration as mobile and desktop application uri's.

[image]

Comment: i'm not looking for mobile app things. See In Azure AD Authentication for  (Desktop + devices) platform as looking.

Comment: hello @Nataraj , sorry for the confusion . I have added an update to the answer

Comment: If I use type = native is working fine as expected. But type parameter - (Deprecated) soon.

Comment: yes, reply uris are used for native applications only but they will be deprecated soon as well .. and now they are replaced by redirect uris in web.

Answer (score 0):

If I used "type=native" parameter then it working fine as expected. It **type** parameter going to expired soon.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application

Note: By defaults to webapp/api

```
# AAD client app

resource "azuread_application" "aks-aad-client" {
 display_name               = local.app_name
 prevent_duplicate_names    = true
 sign_in_audience           = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
 type                       = "native"

 

 web {
    redirect_uris = ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"]
    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
    }
  }
  
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    resource_access {
      id   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User"]
    description          = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "user"
    enabled              = true
    value                = "Task"
  }
}
```